# Create javascript alert in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, alert

How can I create a javascript alert using PHP?

This does not work `echo "alert('my message')";`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should work if you put it within a <script> tag.

Comment: `"This does not work"` - Yes it does.  Unless you're doing something else wrong.  Maybe you could provide some more context?

Comment: "This does not work" explains itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pop up alert in javascript using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618876/can-i-pop-up-alert-in-javascript-using-php)

Comment: @David message for Jonathon ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the script tag in your echo.

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello World');</script>";
?>
```